# Find max of two columns and populate with value in third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with 4 columns - A, B, C,D and E. I want create groups by column A and then find the max of column B and C and then populate E with the corresponding value present in D as shown in example below.

My expected output:

```
column A    column B    column C    column D    Column E
AA         1           a            12          15
AA         2           d            13          15
AA         3           b            14          15
AA         3           e            15          15
BB         1           c            15          17
BB         1           d            16          17
BB         2           b            17          17
BB         2           a            18          17
CC         1           a            11          0
CC         1           c            10          0
CC         1           b            11          0
CC         1           e            15          0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the dataframe before the grouping, then select the first value from Column D:

```py
df = df.sort_values(
    by=["column A", "column B", "column C", "column D"],
    ascending=[True, False, False, False],
)

df["Column E"] = df.groupby("column A")["column D"].transform("first")
print(df.sort_index())
```

Prints:

```
  column A  column B column C  column D  Column E
0       AA         1        a        12        15
1       AA         2        d        13        15
2       AA         3        b        14        15
3       AA         3        e        15        15
4       BB         1        c        15        17
5       BB         1        d        16        17
6       BB         2        b        17        17
7       BB         2        a        18        17
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was really quick and easy fix! It worked like a charm.

Comment: the actual problem is because of the if condition I am applying for populating column E. I am updating the question, can you please see what I am doing wrong with my code and advice how I can change it? Thank you and sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @PushpaGadde I'd suggest to revert the last change in your question and create a new question here on StackOverflow. I'll try to look at it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68290913/find-max-of-two-columns-and-populate-with-value-in-third-column-based-on-a-condi  @Andrej Kesely - added the new question. Thank you for your help.